# T-sql While loop creating html code for an email. How do I dynamically change the table name and variable name in this loop?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, html-email, dynamic-sql

I am trying to create an email system in sql server. There are a lot of details for this email. I need 3 to infinity tables in this email. 
I also need headers above each table.

My issue is creating the xml code in a loop while changing table names and variables.

The tables are all created from different tables in sql, lets call this table 
"dbo.additional_info" Since there are multiple summaries there are multiple tables
 so there is dbo.additional_info1 dbo.additional_info2 and so on.

For this example lets say I have 3 tables and 3 variables.

```
dbo.additional_info1
dbo.additional_info2
dbo.additional_info3
@var1
@var2
@var3
```

Here is the code I have built out:

```
DECLARE @SP tinyint  -- start point 
DECLARE @EP tinyint  -- end point 
DECLARE @body NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @xml2 NVARCHAR(MAX)
declare @var1 varchar(10)
declare @var2 nvarchar(10)  
declare @var3 nvarchar(10)  


set @var1 = 'James'; 
set @var2  = 'Jess'; 
set @var3 = 'Henry'
set @EP = 3
set @SP = 1

SET @body = '
<table border = 1> 
<tr>
<th> Last Name </th> </tr>
'
```

```
set @xml2 = ''

while (@SP < @EP) 
begin 


 set @xml2 =  @xml2 + 
(case when @var1 in  (select name from dbo.names)   
then  '<H3>Info' + convert(varchar,@SP) + (select Location from dbo.names where name = @var1)+ ' Summary</H3>' 
else '<H3>Info' + convert(varchar,@SP) + @var1 + 'Not available </H3>'  end) +
 @body +
 Convert(nvarchar(max), (SELECT
                 [details] as [td], ''

          FROM  dbo.Additional_info1 --- then 2 then 3 
          Order by  [Age]
       For XML path('tr'), Type))
    +'</table>' 
set @sp+=1;


end 

print(@xml2)
```

The code above works but I want the tablename and the @var to adjust each time @Sp increments.  I think the code should look like below: 
I have tried the code below plus 100 different things and no dice.

Any suggestions? I am not familiar with html/xml at all, I am really trying but  don't know where to go from here.

```
 set @xml2 =  @xml2 + 
(case when  concat(@var,  convert(varchar,@SP)) in  (select name from dbo.names)   
then  '<H3>Info' + convert(varchar,@SP) + (select Location from dbo.names where name =  concat((@var or '@var'?),  convert(varchar,@SP)))+ ' Summary</H3>' 
else '<H3>Info' + convert(varchar,@SP) + @var1 + 'Not available </H3>'  end) +
 @body +
 Convert(nvarchar(max), (SELECT
                 [details] as [td], ''

            FROM  concat(dbo.additional_info,  convert(varchar,@SP))

          Order by  [Age]
       For XML path('tr'), Type))
    +'</table>' 
set @sp+=1;


end 

print(@xml2) 

I want the email to look like this: 

Info 1:  Location: America -- this is for @var1 
Table with a few rows of "details."
```

Comment: You've tagged dynamic SQL, however, i don't see anything dynamic here. I also doubt you need a `WHILE`. What does the data in your table look like? What is the end results you're after?

Comment: @Larnu The reason I tagged dynamic was because I think using a dynamic method is a possible solution but I haven't solved it with that method.  I do need to use a while loop, but if you have a more efficient idea I would love to hear it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clarify, in your post you have

> FROM dbo.Additional_info1 --- then 2 then 3

Is this the part you want to be dynamic, where you pull from table 1, then 2, then 3?
If yes, try this.
Note that I did not build tables to recreate, but it should be close. Let me know if it doesn't work! The trick is that you have to build the full text string for what every you want to call into a variable, then call that variable as if it's a function. When I test these, I print the variable (print (@DynamicSqlHere);) before I try executing (exec (@DynamicSqlHere);). If you can copy and paste the printed output, an that output gives you what you expected, then you have what you need.

```
DECLARE @SP tinyint  -- start point 
DECLARE @EP tinyint  -- end point 
DECLARE @body NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @xml2 NVARCHAR(MAX)
declare @var1 varchar(10)
declare @var2 nvarchar(10)  
declare @var3 nvarchar(10)  


set @var1 = 'James'; 
set @var2  = 'Jess'; 
set @var3 = 'Henry'
set @EP = 3
set @SP = 1

SET @body = '
<table border = 1> 
<tr>
<th> Last Name </th> </tr>
'


set @xml2 = ''


while (@SP < @EP) 
begin 

declare @Location nvarchar(200) = (select Location from dbo.names where name = @var1)
declare @DynamicTableCallHere nvarchar(2000) = ''
declare @Message nvarchar(max) =    (case   
                                    when @Location is not null then '<H3>Info' + convert(varchar,@SP) + @Location + ' Summary</H3>' 
                                    when @Location is null then '<H3>Info' + convert(varchar,@SP) + @var1 + 'Not available </H3>' 
                                    end
                                    )

declare @DynamicSqlHere nvarchar(max) = 'set @DynamicTableCallHere = (Convert(nvarchar(max), (SELECT [details] as [td], '''' FROM  dbo.Additional_info' + @sp + ' Order by  [Age] For XML path(''tr''), Type)))'
exec (@DynamicSqlHere);

set @xml2 = @xml2 +
+ @Message
+ @body
+ @DynamicTableCallHere
+ '</table>';

set @sp+=1;


end 

print(@xml2)
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server does not support macro substitution so that leaves Dynamic SQL or a little hack as illustrated below.

This also assumes your tables have identical structures, you can define a variable `@GetTable`

**Example**

```
...
FROM ( Select * From dbo.Additional_info1 Where @GetTable=1
       Union All
       Select * From dbo.Additional_info2 Where @GetTable=2
       Union All
       Select * From dbo.Additional_info3 Where @GetTable=3
     ) SrcData
...
```